# Asignar objeto de una clase y a objeto de una clase x

Tags: c#

alguien sabe como puedo hacer lo siguiente:
tengo una clase X y otra Y, ambas tienen los mismos atributos en el mismo orden y demas, practicamente son identicas solo que con diferente nombre, entonces quiero hacer algo como:

```
X objX = new X(....);
Y objY = objX;
```

Alguien sabe si hacer eso se puede???

Answer (score 4):

Existe la Herencia:

```
// Clase A (Padre)
class A
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public A(int x, int y) { this.X = x; this.Y = y; }
}

// Clase B : Hijo
class B : A
{
    public int Z; // Extendimos la clase A, en la clase B.
    public B(int x, int y) : base(x, y) { Z = 0; }
}
```

Y al llamarlos podemos hacer así:

```
B Child = new B(2, 3); // X = 2, Y = 3, Z = 0;
A Parent = B; // Z practicamente no existe, pero puede ser accesible con un cast.
```

Y pues, aparte de la herencia, tambien existe algo así como una copia, que creo que se adapta más a tu caso, dado que tienes dos clases con los mismos miembros...

Imagina que tenemos la clase A:

```
class A
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public A(...) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Y una clase B:

```
class B
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
    public B(...) { /* ... */ }
    public B(A elem) 
    {
        this.X = A.X;
        this.Y = A.Y;
    }
}
```

Si te fijas, en la clase `A` y `B` tenemos los mismos atributos, lo que las vuelve diferentes es el identificador, en la clase `B` he puesto un constructor copia, que cumple con lo que buscas y no necesitas heredar ninguna clase, por lo que si quieres tener los mismos valores de una variable tipo `A` en una tipo `B`:

```
A MiObjeto = new A(5, 3); // X = 5, Y = 3.
B MiSegundoObjeto = new B(A); // Donde se llama al constructor copia.
```

Si probamos:

```
Console.WriteLine("A.X: " + A.X + ", B.X: " + B.X); // Ambos imprimen 5
Console.WriteLine("A.Y: " + A.Y + ", B.Y: " + B.Y); // Ambos imprimen 3
```

La diferencia entre ambas es que el constructor copia crea una nueva instancia con todos los miembros accesibles desde su propia instancia, mientras que la herencia oculta los miembros agregaste o extendiste desde tu nueva clase Hija, aunque se puede acceder a ella por medio de un cast (siguiendo la herencia):

```
B Nueva = (B)A; // Obliga a la clase a convertirse en la clase hija.
```

Answer (score 2):

Si implementas `herencia` en las clases podrias asignarlas como mencionas

Un ejemplo

```
public class Y 
{
    public string Prop1 {get;set;}
    public int Prop2 {get;set;}
}

public class X : Y
{
    public string Prop3 {get;set;}
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        X objX = new X();
        Y objY = objX;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Eso se soluciona utilizando herencia, creas una clase padre utilizando los campos que ambas clases comparten y en las clases hijas utilizas los campos diferentes, aquí un ejemplo:

```
// WorkItem implicitly inherits from the Object class.
public class WorkItem
{
// Static field currentID stores the job ID of the last WorkItem that
// has been created.
private static int currentID;

//propiedades.
protected int ID { get; set; }
protected string Title { get; set; }
protected string Description { get; set; }
protected TimeSpan jobLength { get; set; }

// Constructor por defecto. Si una clase derivada no invoca a un constructor base de manera explicita, el constructor por defecto es llamado de forma implícita

public WorkItem()
{
    ID = 0;
    Title = "Titulo Random";
    Description = "Descripcion Random.";
    jobLength = new TimeSpan();
}

// Instance constructor that has three parameters.
public WorkItem(string title, string desc, TimeSpan joblen)
{
    this.ID = GetNextID();
    this.Title = title;
    this.Description = desc;
    this.jobLength = joblen;
}

// Static constructor to initialize the static member, currentID. This
// constructor is called one time, automatically, before any instance
// of WorkItem or ChangeRequest is created, or currentID is referenced.
static WorkItem()
{
    currentID = 0;
}


protected int GetNextID()
{
    // currentID is a static field. It is incremented each time a new
    // instance of WorkItem is created.
    return ++currentID;
}

// Method Update enables you to update the title and job length of an
// existing WorkItem object.
public void Update(string title, TimeSpan joblen)
{
    this.Title = title;
    this.jobLength = joblen;
}

// Virtual method override of the ToString method that is inherited
// from System.Object.
public override string ToString()
{
    return String.Format("{0} - {1}", this.ID, this.Title);
}
}

// ChangeRequest derives from WorkItem and adds a property (originalItemID) 
// and two constructors.
public class ChangeRequest : WorkItem
{
protected int originalItemID { get; set; }

// Constructors. Because neither constructor calls a base-class 
// constructor explicitly, the default constructor in the base class
// is called implicitly. The base class must contain a default 
// constructor.

// Default constructor for the derived class.
public ChangeRequest() { }

// Instance constructor that has four parameters.
public ChangeRequest(string title, string desc, TimeSpan jobLen,
                     int originalID)
{
    // The following properties and the GetNexID method are inherited 
    // from WorkItem.
    this.ID = GetNextID();
    this.Title = title;
    this.Description = desc;
    this.jobLength = jobLen;

    // Property originalItemId is a member of ChangeRequest, but not 
    // of WorkItem.
    this.originalItemID = originalID;
}
}

class Program
{
static void Main()
{
    // Create an instance of WorkItem by using the constructor in the 
    // base class that takes three arguments.
    WorkItem item = new WorkItem("Fix Bugs",
                                 "Fix all bugs in my code branch",
                                 new TimeSpan(3, 4, 0, 0));

    // Create an instance of ChangeRequest by using the constructor in
    // the derived class that takes four arguments.
    ChangeRequest change = new ChangeRequest("Change Base Class Design",
                                             "Add members to the class",
                                             new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0),
                                             1);

    // Use the ToString method defined in WorkItem.
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());

    // Use the inherited Update method to change the title of the 
    // ChangeRequest object.
    change.Update("Change the Design of the Base Class",
        new TimeSpan(4, 0, 0));

    // ChangeRequest inherits WorkItem's override of ToString.
    Console.WriteLine(change.ToString());

    // Keep the console open in debug mode.
    Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}
}
/* Output:
1 - Fix Bugs
2 - Change the Design of the Base Class
*/
```

Referencia: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms173149.aspx